# Chef Server and Workstation installation in same p.c

Tags: chef-infra

I am working on CHEF framework, I am able to install workstation and chef server in two different p.c. Now I am trying to put my work station and server in a single P.c. How to do that?

Comment: You haven't tried before asking?

Answer (score 0):

Just download and install. It should not end up on any conflict.